# Accessing Object data in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, object, repeater

I have a repeater on my asp.net web forms page.

The repeater data source is a list of "OrderLine" objects.

Each repeater item has a TextBox control that displays the quantity of the order line.

When the quantity in the textbox control is changed, there is an auto postback to recalculate the total and discount value properties of the OrderLine object.

My question is, is there a better way to access the object data directly instead of getting the index of the repeater item and using that to get the object list index like below?

I'd like to access the object directly if possible rather than create temporary variables.

```
protected void txtLineQuantity_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     RepeaterItem rItem = (RepeaterItem)((Control)sender).NamingContainer;
     int i = rItem.ItemIndex;

     decimal netPrice = OrderLines[i].NetPrice;
     decimal netTotal = OrderLines[i].NetTotal;
     int qty = OrderLines[i].Quantity;
     decimal weight = OrderLines[i].Weight;

     TextBox txtLineQuantity = (TextBox)rItem.FindControl("txtLineQuantity");

     //... do calculations and bind data to repeater control
}
```

If i've missed any info that's needed please let me know...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a HiddenField control to RepeaterItem. Bind data to HiddenField.

ASP

```
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenNetPrice" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("NetPrice") %>' />
          <!--Other Controls
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

C#

```
RepeaterItem rItem = (RepeaterItem)((Control)sender).NamingContainer;
var hiddenNetPrice= rItem.FindControl("hiddenNetPrice") as HiddenField;
var netPrice = hiddenNetPrice.Value;
```